# Snort symlink explanation

Tags: linux, unix, symlink, snort

I would like to ask why there is symlink needed

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/snort /usr/sbin/snort
```

while installing snort from

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/122/original/Snort_2.9.9.x_on_Ubuntu_14-16.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1492113643&Signature=K1ZQFFgsQ2qoGvePuW5oS4LhOF8%3D
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of having two copies of the same files/directories you create a symlink to the folder on one location so both paths refer to the same batch of files and you only have to update one set.

This is not too useful for something accessing the batch of files in the dir, but more useful for snort when updating the files, so it only has to update one set of files.

**in short**, keeping track of one set of files in one location is easier than two sets of the same files in two different locations.

Comment: Ty for answer, but i know what symlink do or what is it used for, but i just dont know why i need it in /usr/sbin/snort, anyway i have launched it from usr/local/bin/snort every time.